# How to develop a rapid database & web application using Sybase and Power Builder?

Tags: database, reference, sybase, powerbuilder

I am new in Sybase and Power Builder.

What are the best references and web resources to learn them in a useful and fast way ?

For now, I use http://www.sybase.com as my base reference.

Does anyone know good and practical tutorials for Power Builder V.12 .Net ?
From Where I can download a complete version of it and use it for building my application ?

I know the data window is the magical part in Power Builder and I need to know how to create and use a professional data window and how to make interaction and pass paramters between them and also how to dispaly different views like Master-Detail relationship and Tree-Sturcture or List-Structure and so on.

I would like to know the information I need to build a rapid web and database application plus customzing and editing the existing desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 45 trial version of Powerbuilder which you can download from here:

- http://response.sybase.com/forms/PB12Eval

Sybase's books that come with Powerbuilder are fairly comprehensive and quite a good way to get started.

- http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.infocenter.pb.12.1/doc/html/title.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with Powerbuilder but Rob Verschoor's [Sypron.nl](http://www.sypron.nl/main.html) is the place to pick up Sybase information - there's loads in there from common "gotachas" to quizzes. His [quick reference](http://www.sypron.nl/qr/) is terrific and well worth investing in.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends on how much experience you already have (not counting Sybase & PB).

Then there is the issue that app development and Db design are completely different disciplines: people who are good at one are rarely good at the other.  Assuming you are the app developer, hire a good modeller/DBA.  Product manuals are for reference only; you cannot learn how to code; put an app together; what code segments should be deployed where; best practice; etc from them.

To take even reasonable advantage of the DataWindow, you need a good Database (normalised, genuinely relational, security, etc), AND reasonable experience handling the client/server model (send SQL batch to server; receive & process result set).

You need a good PFC Library.  The lib that comes with PB is fat as, and very slow.  The first thing we do is strip that down, and create our own, to reduce .pbl size and increase speed.
Last but not least, a good handle on stored proc and Transaction rules.  That requirement is true for any app, not just Sybase/Pb.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on what you want to do. PB12 comes with 2 IDEs -- PB12.NET is for creating WPF applications in .NET. PB12 Classic is for creating traditional PB applications as well as WinForm and WebForm .NET type applications.

There are some videos available on PB (some free, some paid)

Yakov Werde has a video titled "Essential PowerBuilder Series" that's about $700. You can see a free preview of it [here](http://www.yakovwerde.com/eLearnIT/PBCourseOverview/player.html).

Sybase has some free videos and tutorials [here](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerbuilder/powerbuilder-videos).

Also, there are some older PowerBuilder books like "PowerBuilder 9 Advanced Client/Server Development" that may help you. They're a little dated and don't cover any of the .NET stuff, but a lot of the basics are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for has always been somewhat of a challenge to find.  Without all the corporate training I'm not sure how I would have learned as quickly.

If you are like me then learning by example is probably the best way. I'd go to codeplex and get yourself a working (and well designed) application to learn by example.

Also, believe it or not, I have learned a thing or two by reading the online documentation. Considering you are working with a new version of PB you've got your work cut out for you there isn't much out there. You may contact me if you have specific questions, if I have time then I would be happy to help a fellow developer.